# Como salvar em um caminho relativo?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
private string SubirImagem(string imagemupload, string sequencia, string clifor)
{
    HttpPostedFile imagem = Request.Files[imagemupload];
    string nomeimagem = "";

    if (imagem != null && imagem.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string extimagem = Path.GetExtension(imagem.FileName).ToLower();
        nomeimagem = clifor + '_' + sequencia + extimagem;
        imagem.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("/Uploads", (nomeimagem))));
    }

    return nomeimagem;
}
```

Local esse método esta funcionando normalmente, hospedado ele esta apresentando erro informando que eu não tenho permissão para gravação na pasta:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "caminhodoservidor"\httpdocs\Uploads\510247_1.png is denied.

Gostaria de saber como faço para salvar em um caminho relativo?
Ou alguma outra forma de fazer o método acima.

Comment: Você precisa de permissão de escrita nesta página, só isso.

Comment: Segundo a empresa que esta hospedando a aplicação essa permissão já foi concedida.

Comment: A pasta Uploads realmente existe?

Comment: Onde está a aplicação dentro da estrutura apresentada? Solta em **httpdocs**? Ou dentro de uma pasta em **httpdocs**?

Comment: Sim, existe localmente a aplicação funciona sem problemas.

Comment: Solta na raiz do httpdocs.

Comment: Tem como mostrar a estrutura de pastas?

Comment: A maioria, se não todos, dos servidores de hospedagem compartilhados configuram as pastas com acesso apenas de leitura, geralmente você deve usar o painel de controle ou entrar em contato com o suporte para dar permissão de gravação para essa pasta, sendo recomendado remover a permissão de execução desta pasta também.

Comment: http://imgur.com/md2aMSq

Comment: Ok, mas qual é a pasta do print?

Comment: Uploads, essa pasta que esta apresentando o erro de permissão.

Comment: A pasta que você estava no momento do print é a pasta **Uploads**? Então toda a aplicação está dentro da pasta Uploads? Não parece ser isso.

Comment: Não tinha entendido sua pergunta ,no momento que esta sendo chamado o método eu no pasta **Pages**

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa Liguei no provedor e realmente eles não tinham dado a permissão que eu havia solicitado antes, estava na certeza que o problema era no codigo já que a permissão já havia sido concedido.
Muito obrigado por ter gerado essa duvida novamente, a aplicação esta funcionando hospedada agora!

Comment: @LINQ muito obrigado pela ajuda! O problema foi um erro operacional na empresa de hospedagem, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo!